# Select by range of letters

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, glob, sql-like

Table `students` I am trying to sort by names for letters in range A-M:

[image: Here is the table contents]

[image: Here is when i run the command]

I've tried:

```
SELECT *  FROM student  WHERE student_first_name like '[A-M]%';
```

It's not giving me anything.

Comment: As you can see they let you choose between several different dbms:es. Hint: You can switch around and see if it makes any difference!

Comment: @jarlh I'm intrigued - which RDBMS's LIKE has regex support? I'd consider it very confusing if I had to escape characters like '.' or '[' in a simple LIKE search.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, SQL Server would accept OP's query. https://dbfiddle.uk/wL2X1J1S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SQLite which supports the [`GLOB`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators) operator where you can use the `[x-y]` list wildcard and `*` instead of `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_first_name GLOB '[A-M]*';
```

Note that `GLOB` is case sensitive.

If you want case insensitive results use:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE UPPER(student_first_name) GLOB '[A-M]*';
```

Comment: Tysm that actually worked, But any idea why its not containing a name that starts with an A letter ?

Edit: It was just case sensitive actually tysm its working perfectly
Another Edit: anyway i can make it actually not case sensitive ? because i don't have the UPPER operator and its still case sensitive

Comment: @Foze As I mention in my answer GLOB is case sensitive. Use the 2nd query if you have names starting with `a` or `A`. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ckr8noOJ

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in SQL, But I have tested below query in MySQL it's working fine for me.

Please use `REGEXP` like below:

```
SELECT * FROM student  WHERE student_first_name REGEXP '^[A-M]';
```

Comment: I will try it in a bit when i get to my computer. But any idea why like isn’t working ?

Comment: @Foze directly regular expression not working in like operator. if you need to use like then you should use `REGEXP_LIKE()` instead of `LIKE`. please follow the document here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-3FA7F5AB-AC64-4200-8F90-294101428C26

Answer (score 1):

[SQLight LIKE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/) only supports `%` and `_`. For what you are trying to do you can use [GLOB](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-glob/) instead.

> The GLOB operator is similar to the LIKE operator. Unlike the LIKE operator, the GLOB operator is case sensitive and uses the UNIX wildcards.

Comment: I just tried GLOB with or without square brackets and it still doesn't work with SQLlite Online

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` operator doesn't support character classes - only wildcards.

To get all names starting with A-M, you can

- use 13 LIKE expressions and OR them

  `where last_name like 'A%' or last_name like 'B%' or ... or last_name like 'M%'`
- use your RDBMS' flavour of regular expression matching

  `where last_name ~ '^[A-M]'`
- use your RDBMS' function for getting the first character of the string and compare it to a an `IN` list

  `where substr(last_name, 1, 1) in ('A', 'B', ..., 'M')`

[SQL Fiddle (PostgreSQL)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a0ade1/4)

Answer (score 1):

Your version did not work because you asked it to give you all the students whose name begins with a square bracket and it rightly told you there are none.

In addition to the other answers, you can also use `Where first_name between 'A' And 'N' And first_name<'N'`.

This version has a much better chance of being faster by using any indexes there may be on the first_name column because you are not performing a calculation on it.

Comment: I tried without the square brackets and it still didn't work, i am trying to use the like to work because some dude told me it can work like that but i still cant figure it out